# Functional way to have two toggles that turn each other off

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, dom, ecmascript-6

I have two sets of toggles that need to "uncheck" each other. This is my current solution which is working.  Can it somehow get more functional/elegant?

```
let unscheduledLayerToggles = [unscheduledLayerToggle, unscheduledLayerToggleToolbar];
let availableLayerToggles = [availableLayerToggle, availableLayerToggleToolbar];

flipToggles(firstToggles, secondToggles)
flipToggles(secondToggles, firstToggles)

function flipToggles(firstToggles, secondToggles) {
    firstToggles.forEach(function (toggle) {
        on(toggle, "change", function () {
            secondToggles.forEach(function(element) {
                element.checked = false
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: I would have tagged each set of toggles with a class and used that instead. Especially if you are using something like jQuery it is easy to perform an operation on multiple elements matching a class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logic itself is simple enough. I see that you are using ECMAScript 6, with it there are some things you could do to simplify the code and make it more robust.

### `const`

You are using `let` for `unscheduledLayerToggles` and `availableLayerToggles`, which is fine, but in the case that you will not be reassigning different values/arrays to those names, you could simply use `const` instead of `let`. Note that this will not make the arrays immutable, so you can still manipulate their contents, it only disallows assigning something different to them.

### `flipToggles` function

In the same manner as you can use `const` to declare function (in the style of `var foo = function () { ... }`). It helps to make the intentions clear that the function will not change.

### Arrow functions

ES6 provides a great way to both shorten/simplify function declarations, as well as isolate their scope better: [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

The syntax is explained well on MDN like I provided. In the case of your `flipToggles` function, we could write the code this way and eliminate all the unnecessary `function()` declarations.

---

```
const unscheduledLayerToggles = [unscheduledLayerToggle, unscheduledLayerToggleToolbar];
const availableLayerToggles = [availableLayerToggle, availableLayerToggleToolbar];

flipToggles(firstToggles, secondToggles)
flipToggles(secondToggles, firstToggles)

const flipToggles = (firstToggles, secondToggles) => {
  firstToggles.forEach(toggle => {
    on(toggle, "change", () => {
      secondToggles.forEach(element => {
        element.checked = false
      })
    })
  })
}
```

*(mind the indentation, which is a personal preference of mine for 2 spaces indent instead of 4)*

Answer (score 3):

If you'd want to make it more functional, let's first separate logic from effects (gathering user events and manipulating DOM). And then integrate them back.

Considering logic, it begins with some initial state:

```
// to make state checks more natural-language-like
const ON = true;
const OFF = false;
const initialState = {
    firstGroup : ON,
    secondGroup : OFF
}
```

Then we make function that takes previous state and "ACTIVATE_FIRST" or "ACTIVATE_SECOND" command to calculate the next state:

```
function processCommand (state, command) { 
    // in case there would be more than one command
    switch (command) {
        case "ACTIVATE_FIRST":
            return { 
                firstGroup : ON,
                secondGroup : OFF
            }
        case "ACTIVATE_SECOND":
            return { 
                firstGroup : OFF,
                secondGroup : ON
            }
        default:
            throw new Error("Unknown command")
    }
}
```

Then, given a stream of commands, starting with `initialState`, apply reduce (in functional languages it is usually called left fold) RxJS operator to them - and you get stream of states. Conceptually it looks like this: `commands -> process -> states`. It is your functional logic.

Then you need to connect logic with effects. First, using DOM selector subscribe to events from DOM elements and get two RxJS streams: first producing events that should yield "ACTIVATE_FIRST" command, and second for "ACTIVATE_SECOND". Then map these two streams to commands accordingly and merge into single stream of commands. It would be the left part of the stream chain or ***sources***.

Then for the right part or ***sinks*** you should subscribe to a stream of states and finally write simple function that applies given state to DOM.

I don't give more details here, as it is the concept which is important, rather than details. Of course, for such a simple UX this seems like an overkill, but this approach scales great.

If you like it - have a look at CycleJS and Elm.

Comment: Very interesting approach, nicely done!

Comment: I would have used a `Map` instead of `switch`, though that's mainly because I don't like `switch`. Also, you should throw an exception, not a string.

Comment: @Brian-McCutchon What we need here is pattern matching. Which is not present in JavaScript spec. Things get especially interesting when commands are no more simple strings, but some objects or data structures. Like a filter command holding filter conditions. This deserves separate implementation on its own. Map wouldn't suffice either. In this case something like PatternMatchingError might be thrown. Not Exception, as it is not supposed to be handled in runtime, but Error. Thanks for pointing that anyway.

Comment: @iTollu I agree about pattern matching. On the subject of errors and exceptions, I don't think JavaScript really differentiates, I just meant that you should put `throw new Error("Unknown command")` rather than `throw "Unknown command"`, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13016600/2093695).